# Laptop booting to black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lenovo, windows-10

I'm dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 on my Lenovo IdeaPad S540 (AMD version, integrated graphics). It's currently booting, and while the fans come on and the keyboard lights up, the screen does not turn on at all. I can't access BIOS, or Ubuntu or Windows 10. Nothing I press seems to have any effect.

This happened about a week ago too, however that time I was able to access the BIOS and change the boot order as it had changed to Windows first when it should be GRUB. I assume that's what happened this time, but I can't access anything this time.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Trying holding shift+F8 and then pressing the power button. Let go of the power button, but keep holding the others until the screen comes up. If it still doesn't, the most likely problem is a screen cable that has come loose or gotten pinched (assuming the screen has no back light coming on either). Try the buttons first and report back. If it seems like the cable, I can walk you through checking/fixing it.

Comment: Entering the bios is manufacturer/model specific, check the manual for your laptop. You can also try a bios reset(also see the manual, or remove the RTC Coin Battery in your laptop). If you cant enter your bios its probably not a ubuntu/dualboot problem, sounds like a hardware issue.

Comment: I connected it to an external monitor and no signal was put out, which makes it seem like it's nothing to do with the screen. No button combination worked either. @jwcooper

Comment: I dont really have too many more ideas. I can tell you that a few years ago AMD boards had a real problem with the solder balls on the internal graphics chip becoming brittle and then cracking. The symptoms are exactly what you described. If you absolutely cant find anything else it could be, you could try to reflow the motherboard in the oven. You can find the procedure on Youtube. I was incredibly skeptical when I first saw this, but ended up doing it on three different laptops now and they all started working immediately. If you exhaust other troubleshooting, this may be your only option.

Comment: Just one more thing - try and take a flashlight and shine it onto the screen after startup. Sometimes the backlight dies, but the flashlight will allow you to see whether there is actually anything there. Worth a shot.